# Java parallel serialisation and compression

Tags: java, performance, serialization, parallel-processing

I have a JavaSE8 app for processing large dataset in parallel. I am generating 1M objects I would like to serialize into a single compressed file. The file will be downloaded/uploaded from a web app.
The parallel process is well optimized. However the serialization/compression is done sequentially and it's the bottleneck of my app.

I've tested different solution: Kryo, ChronicleMap... I am now using Kryo and Bz2 compression. It's working. But the performance is not good enough.

I can't find any solution for doing parallel serialization and compression. Any information in this regards is welcome

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually matter how you process you dataset either in parallel or sequentially, cause in clear design - serialization is always a sequential (due to sequential nature of output streams, sockets and so forth) operation and stays aside your dataset processing. So if you are going to serialize and put your serialized dataset into file, connection or raw memory you have to define a barrier which will protect data from concurrent races and undesired modifications.

Surely, there are cases when each working thread serializes data itself, such as http server works for example, but here we are talking about single dataset which is being parallel processed and finally serialized.

So, according to above it supposed to be a right code to answer. It uses standard Java serialization + GZIP compression. You can easily replace serialization and/or compression in this code and benchmark against your current solution.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import static java.lang.String.format;

public final class ParallelObjectsSerialization {

    private static final int ONE_MILLION = 1_000_000;
    private static final String SERIALIZE_FILE = "/tmp/out.bin";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
//        List<Player> players = parallelGenerate1MPlayers();
        List<Player> players = seqGenerate1MPlayers();
        serialize(players);
        players.clear();
        players = deserialize();
    }

    private static List<Player> deserialize() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(SERIALIZE_FILE)))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ONE_MILLION; i++) {
                players.add((Player) in.readObject());
            }
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
        System.out.println(format("deserialization of %d objects took %d ms", players.size(), time));
        return players;
    }

    private static final class Player implements Serializable {
        private final String name;
        private final int level;

        private Player(String name, int level) {
            this.name = name;
            this.level = level;
        }
    }

    private static List<Player> seqGenerate1MPlayers() {
        long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>(ONE_MILLION);
        for (int i = 0; i < ONE_MILLION; i++) {
            players.add(new Player(randomName(i), i));
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
        System.out.println(format("sequential generating of %d objects took %d ms", players.size(), time));
        return players;
    }

    private static List<Player> parallelGenerate1MPlayers() {
        long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Player[] players = new Player[ONE_MILLION];
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(players, (i) -> new Player(randomName(i), i));
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
        System.out.println(format("parallel generating of %d objects took %d ms", players.length, time));
        return Arrays.asList(players);
    }

    private static void serialize(List<Player> players) throws IOException {
        long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SERIALIZE_FILE)))) {
            for (Player player : players) {
                out.writeObject(player);
            }
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
        System.out.println(format("serialization of %d objects took %d ms", players.size(), time));
    }

    private static String randomName(int seed) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        double chance = 30.0;
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            if (Math.random() * 100.0 <= chance) {
                builder.append(c);
                if (builder.length() == 7) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (builder.length() == 0) {
            builder.append("unknown").append(seed);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander. I have already tested this solution. It's the bottleneck in the whole process, as serialisation  must be done sequentially.

Comment: What about the splitting collection into multiple smallest collections and serialise them in parallel and group them into zip or tar file?

Comment: i'm afraid in this case ```tar``` would be a bottle neck. As i mentioned in my post - final step will be always a sequential operation. But on the other hand if your serialization is CPU bound and problem appears in CPU utilization during objects serialization, ```tar``` would work on tons of small serialized chunks, but beware of disk I/O saturation then.